# Set a relative Path to run on Tomcat

Tags: nio, filepath

I was hoping to use: classpath:/mydata/response.xml to copy a file to.

like this..
 Path dest = Paths.get("classpath:/mydata/response.xml");

for Spring boot this works elsewhere but not using Paths !

I want to copy a file over thus...

```
                          InputStream is = file.getInputStream();

                          //Which relative Path syntax?
                          Path dest = Paths.get("./src/main/resources/mydata"+fileName);
                          Files.copy(is, dest);
```

any suggestions as to how to set the relative path to store my file on Tomcat?

my target is:

MyProject\src\main\resources\mydata

It's a nice Spring Boot project..

Comment: I recommend as _**strongly**_ as imaginable that you _do not_ put data anywhere within your web application's directory hierarchy.  Doing so will make upgrading to new versions of your app difficult to do; you can forget about doing a simple war drop for deployments.

Comment: Hmm that's right.  So setting an absolute path on the server in my case Tomcat would be better.  i still wouldn't mind knowing how to set the relative path as described above.

Comment: If you have `HttpServletRequest request` you can use `request.getServletContext().getRealPath("./foo/bar.html");` to get the actual filesystem path of the dir/file given. This may be something like `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/yourapp/foo/bar.html`. Or if you save the ServletContext somewhere earlier, just `context.getRealPath(".....")`. See [docs for getRealPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) ... however this doesn't answer your question about being _relative to the **classpath**_.

Answer (score 1):

Using a path relative to the `CLASSPATH` isn't really achievable, since the classpath is a *list* of directories and/or jar files.  If there are multiple directories, which one should you use? If there are *only* jar files it makes no sense at all.
One of our Tomcat server startup scripts begins the classpath like this:

```
CLASSPATH=$CATALINA_HOME/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:\
$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:\
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/commons-daemon.jar:\
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

If you would like, instead, to store/access files that are within your web application space, you can use the [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) to resolve paths relative you your application's installation directory. Use the [`getRealPath()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath-java.lang.String-) but take care because it may return "null if the translation cannot be performed".

Storing anything within the filesystem structure of your web application can lead to many problems, since a re-deployment would then have to preserve the added files or destroy them.
I recommend instead to create a *configurable* data directory, where the root of that directory could be specified in, for example, a `.properties` file, or as an `<init-param>` in your web.xml file (or other deployment descriptor depending on what framework(s) you may be using).